# Request processing failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()

Tags: spring, jdbc

I am new to spring framework and I am in training. As given by my TL I am trying to finish the task to insert the data into database table by using following methods in controller.

> Create a controller. (UserController.java)
>
> it should have two methods submit() and showAllUsers()

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user")User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showAllUsers() {
    // ...
}
```

I finished the code but I am getting the following error:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

My `UserDaoImpl` code:

```
package com.baylogic.peoplecentral.dao.impl;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.baylogic.peoplecentral.dao.UserDao;
import com.baylogic.peoplecentral.pojo.User;

public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    DataSource dataSource;

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return this.dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public boolean createUser(String firstname, String lastname, int id, String email) throws SQLException {
        String query = "insert into user(firstname,lastname,id,email) values(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setString(1, firstname);
        pstmt.setString(2, lastname);
        pstmt.setInt(3, id);
        pstmt.setString(4, email);
        ResultSet resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next())
            return (resultSet.getInt(1)>0);
        else
            return false;
    } 
}
```

I am stuck and not able to move forward in this task. Would you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the error message, operations like INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE are usually not appropriate for the `executeQuery` method, which is intended for use with statements that return a result set. You should use `executeUpdate` instead.